# Calculating Pi to the Nth digit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to enter in a number and  calculate pi to that digit input. I managed to be able to calculate Pi, however no matter what number I type it will still generate the same amount of Pi numbers.

I'm a bit confused at what point it's causing to do that

```
from math import factorial
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
# Chudnovsky algorithm for figuring out pi
getcontext().prec=100

pi_input = input('How many digits of pi would you like?')
n = int(pi_input)

def calc(n):
    t= Decimal(0)
    pi = Decimal(0)
    deno= Decimal(0)

    for k in range(n):
        t = ((-1)**k)*(factorial(6*k))*(13591409+545140134*k)
        deno = factorial(3*k)*(factorial(k)**3)*(640320**(3*k))
        pi += Decimal(t)/Decimal(deno)
    pi = pi * Decimal(12) / Decimal(640320 ** Decimal(1.5))
    pi = 1/pi
    return pi

print calc(n)
```

Here is my output

```
How many digits of pi would you like? 5 

3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816346
94690247717268165239156011
```

Comment: What makes you think it will produce `n` decimals? As far as I can see it will produce better results with a higher `n` but certainly not exactly `n` digits. And no, the result is different if you change `n`.

Comment: Without analyzing the code: what do you mean with your output? Show an example! It is possible, that the output is just a floating-point print and therefore the number of digits seen is not dependent on how many digits you computed? Be more verbose

Comment: To be clear, you will output the same amount of digits regardless of what n you pick, but the result will be more accurate with higher n.

Comment: Updated my output, I guess I am confused how I can make my function perform the calculation based on the input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the Chudnovsky algorithm, the calculation produces about 14.18 decimal digits per iteration: `log10((640320^3)/(24*6*2*6)) ~= 14.18`. This can be more clearly seen in the formula for a<sub>k</sub> / a<sub>k-1</sub> as shown on this web page:

https://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-chudnovsky

For n = 5, the result has about 70 digits of precision.

Answer (score 2):

I just added round function in the return statement in your code and hope and it works for you as it for me.

```
from math import factorial
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
# Chudnovsky algorithm for figuring out pi
getcontext().prec=1000

pi_input = input('How many digits of pi would you like?')
n = int(pi_input)

def cal(n):
    t= Decimal(0)
    pi = Decimal(0)
    deno= Decimal(0)

    for k in range(n):
        t = ((-1)**k)*(factorial(6*k))*(13591409+545140134*k)
        deno = factorial(3*k)*(factorial(k)**3)*(640320**(3*k))
        pi += Decimal(t)/Decimal(deno)
    pi = pi * Decimal(12) / Decimal(640320 ** Decimal(1.5))
    pi = 1/pi
    return round(pi,n)

print(cal(n))
```

Comment: But this is calculating the whole thing first, so is very resourcce inneficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `"%.nf"`to format the output string where `n` is the number of digits you want to output. 
e.g.

```
import numpy as np
print "%.5f"%(np.pi)
```

Comment: not work for an N greater than 50 `3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500000000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import factorial
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

n = int(input('How many digits of pi would you like?'))
# Chudnovsky algorithm for figuring out pi
getcontext().prec=n+1
def calc(n):
    t= Decimal(0)
    pi = Decimal(0)
    deno= Decimal(0)
    k=0

    #t = ((-1)**k)*(factorial(6*k))*(13591409+545140134*k)
    t=(1)*(factorial(1))*(13591409+545140134*k)
    deno = factorial(3*k)*(factorial(k)**3)*(640320**(3*k))
    pi += Decimal(t)/Decimal(deno)
    pi = pi * Decimal(12) / Decimal(640320 ** Decimal(1.5))
    pi = 1/pi
    return pi

print (calc(n))
```

Comment: Along with the code, you should also add a description of the solution you're proposing.

Comment: it's in the comment

Answer (score -1):

this might be a simple code for understanding

```
from numpy import *

n = int(input('How many digits of pi after decimal would you like to print'))
print(pi)

#print (" value of pi at {:.4f} is" .format(pi))

print('{pi:0.{precision}f}'.format(pi=pi,precision=n))
```

Answer (score -1):

this is how I would do it :-)

```py
import math
digits = int(input("to how many digits to you want to round PI?"))

def roundpi(n):
    return round(pi,n)

roundpi(digits)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this and let me know if it works for you

```
import numpy as np

def pi_nth(n):
    new_str = ''
    for i in range(n+2):
        new_str += str(np.pi)[i]
    return float(new_str)
```

Comment: rather than iterating you could use a slice, given that you're not calculating pi, per se.

Comment: This works only up to a limit of 15 decimal places since `pi` value imported from numpy or math consists of `3.141592653589793`.

Answer (score -1):

I answered the same question the short way using PI from the math module.

```
from math import pi
print()
nums = int(input("Enter the number of decimals: "))
print("Pi to the {}th number of decimals is %.{}f".format(nums, nums) % (pi))
```

Output

```
Enter the number of decimals: 5
Pi to the 5th number of decimals is 3.14159
```

This is in python 3.8 hope it helps.

Comment: nope after 48 digits it just shows 0000000000........

Answer (score -1):

```
#To print the Nth decimal place values of pi
from math import pi
#Receive the input value for number of decimal points of pi needed from user
i=input("Enter the number of decimal places needed in pi")
#Variable to hold the pi value upto nth decimal.Assign it to empty string initially
n_val=""
#Convert the pi value to string 
string_pi=str(pi) 

    x=0
    #loop through each literals and add the value to a string variable and then print it
    while x<=int(i)+1:
        n_val+=string_pi[x]
        x=x+1
    print(n_val)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from math import pi

num = int(input('Enter the number of decimals: '))

print(f"Pi upto {num}th number is {pi:{1}.{num+1}}")
```

Comment: Such sulution was already proposed by multiple answers, why to add one more?